# Video streaming in Django: can it be done the same way as flask?

Tags: python, django, streaming

The following method from Miguel Grinberg has worked quite well for me in Flask, but I'm migrating my app to Django, and I was wondering if this can be recreated with built-in Django functions?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from camera import Camera

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(Camera()),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

This works quite well because my streams are motionJPEG, and that's what this code was designed for.

I'm specifically wondering about the `Response(gen(Camera)), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace';boundary=frame')` bit. how would I use a generator to place an incoming frame onto a url/route defined in urls.py?

Comment: You can use streaming http responses in Django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#streaminghttpresponse-objects

Comment: I'm exactly looking for the same solution! :)  If you find one please alert me. Thanks!

Comment: @Miguel I have yet to implement it, but it looks like you just use the same code, but replace Response() with django's built-in StreamingHttpResponse() method. There may be some other tweaks needed, but they appear to be equivalent.